# Find triplets in an array such that sum of two numbers is also a number in the given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array, such as `[1, 0, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, find all subsets of length three where one element is equal to the sum of the other two elements in the subset. For example:

```
1 + -1 == 0 (from [1, 0, -1])
2 +  3 == 5 (from [2, 3, 5])
```

I came up with an `O(n²)` solution, but my interviewer insisted that there is an `O(n log n)` solution.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: How many subsets are there if the array is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]?

Comment: @JasonL probably unique subsets (there's really no point otherwise). Or, maybe the given array is a set/unique (also makes more sense).

Comment: I presume the interviewer is after the count only? Because there are O(n^2) number of such subsets and enumerating them would take O(n^2) e.g. array [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

Comment: Yup N Choose 2. N!/(2!*(N-1)!) = N(N-1) or O(n^2). That was my argument. Maybe they were looking to throw me off

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and answers! I appreciate it. I needed some validation for my thought process :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I can't see an algorithm that is less than `O(n²)`.  (Unless it is an extra-ordinarily clever one)

This problem is very similar to the infamous 3SUM question: Basically, the idea is that given a set of n elements, are there any triples that sum to zero?

An algorithm solving 3SUM faster than `O(n²)` is not known - This is an open problem in computer science... (See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)

However, since your question is not exactly 3SUM (`A+B+C=0`), rather it involves (`A+B=C`), we cannot immediately preclude clever tricks (but we do make them very unlikely).

That being said, your problem can be transformed into `A+B-C=0`, which seems to me that such a solution would solve 3SUM in less than `O(n²)` as well...

---

Consider this solution for such a problem:

Consider a solution to the 2SUM problem (that is, finding 2 element lists that sum to a certain value). We can Hash every element in the array (or some other data type with constant time lookup).  Inserting every element takes `O(n)` time. This is the linear solution to a 2SUM problem. (One then loops over every element in the array and checks the hash for `T-element`)

Taking this idea, we can hash every sum in the array.  However, getting every possible combination takes `n*(n-1)` or `O(n²)` time at best.

---

If anyone does have a solution faster than `O(n²)` I will be forever in awe of your number-fu (and if I find one, I will edit this and eat my words).

Good Luck in your search!

Comment: Yes that was my argument to the interviewer as well. To pick pairs of 2s from N elements it would lead to N Choose 2 combinations which comes to n!/(2!*(n-2)!) which comes to n*(n-1). It's mathematically impossible.:) I'm not sure what they were looking for.

Comment: First glance, he was possibly thinking of 2SUM, Greatest Subsequence, etc... that do have algorithms less than `O(n²)`.  Pretty sure this one does not though... O.o

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure she was looking for these triplets. I ensured that by asking and showing her what I had understood :). She confirmed it. The question wasn't around greatest sub-sequence since I know that algorithm. My guess is since that I finished the problem fairly quickly so she tried to throw me off or probably wanted to hear different approaches. Thank you once again! Hopefully I'll get that job!

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same question [here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-the-triplets/0) , the only difference being that it considers only positive integers.

The point is that, according to the constraints of this question it also demands an `O(n log(n))` solution but the editorial and solution code gives an `O(n²)` solution which gets an AC on submission.

Maybe your interviewer saw this question somewhere but did not go through the solution.

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT SOLUTION:
Time Complexity: O(N**3)
I have used three nested loops to find if any element from any of the loop is equal to the sum of other two. Although, it's not the best solution but I will update this space when I come up with a optimized solution.

SOL:

```
function triplet(N,arr) {
    let ans = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<N-2; i++) {
        for (let j=i+1; j<N-1; j++) {
            for (let k=j+1; k<N; k++) {
                if (arr[i]==arr[j]+arr[k] || arr[j]==arr[k]+arr[i]
                || arr[k]==arr[j]+arr[i]) {
                    ans = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    return ans;
}
```